# Different PDF output for Windows and Linux version 2.1.1

Tags: html, linux, windows, pdf, phantomjs

guys, i have a problem with converting presentation from html to pdf with using phantomjs
On windows i get next result:
[image]

but after deploying on heroku i use phantomjs version for linux and there i get next:
[image]

I do not understand why on linux version of phantomjs picture changes it scale. i saw similar problems happened in other people but their problem wasn't solved.

Comment: Very ooooooooooold bug here but AFAIK phantomjs is discontinued then...

Comment: bad, is there a way to deal with this ?

Comment: Assuming you can _detect_ it's running on Linux (`window.navigator.userAgent`) then you might load a CSS patch. I have a vague memory about it but...well...it's just memory (tricks using `zoom` or setting the container size manually in the CSS, something like that). Not sure, sorry.

Comment: so, i fixed it but i am not sure that is way correct, i set in my css file `html {zoom: 0.68}` and now it is looking normal

Comment: Yep it's hacky and it has to be used only on Linux. Maybe there is something better (more related to the root cause of the bug) but I can't remember what